# Disable a filter in a certain module/action in Symfony

Tags: symfony1, filter, symfony-1.4

I have a filter that queries the DB to check if the Username matches the Password. If it returns false, the filter redirects to "logout" action. The only problem is that it will enter an infinite loop, because the filter applies on "logout" action too.

Is there any way I can 'turn off' the filter for that action only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to perform a check inside the filter. You can get the current module and action from $this->context->getModuleName() and $this->context->getActionName(). Or you could check on the current route name, $this->context->getRouting()->getCurrentRouteName().

In fact sfBasicSecurityFilter does exactly the same, disabling forwarding for the login action. Have a look at it's code.

Comment: The malicious downvotes you received should be reversed during the next voter fraud script run.  Wait 24 hours, and then flag again if the problem persists.